# Is there a KeePass password generator profile that includes uppercase and special characters?

Tags: security, password-management, keepass

I'd like a keepass profile that generates passwords like `A@2f701@4fvzq`.
The only formats I see are MAC Address and all lowercase and digits.

Is there a way to setup a profile with more entropy?

(Remember, many services limit then length of the passwords used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **create a new custom profile**

---

- Click the `Generate a Password` button

[image: KeePass Generate Password Button]

- Select `Open Password Generator`

[image: KeePass Generate Password drop-down]

- Check the options you wish to use and then press the `SAVE` icon

[image: KeePass Generate Password dialog]

- Give your new profile a name and press okay

[image: KeePass Save New Password Profile]

- Once saved, your profile will be listed with the other options in your dropdown.

[image: KeePass Generate Password drop-down revised]